# Granite and Kashrus

Tags: halacha, kashrut-kosher

What is the status of granite: year-round vs pesach in regards to Kashrus. Granite for Pesach is kashered by pouring boiling water over it. Year round, what is the status of granite, can granite be used for meat and milk?

Comment: Please explain why you would think that granite can be used for both meaty and milky foods.

Comment: It's quite smooth so I was wondering if it could have the same status as glass

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/15547/koshering-granite

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Koshering granite](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/15547/koshering-granite)

Comment: The question there is about Pesach only. This question is about milk and meat during the year. Any answer would have to discuss the difference and why or why not the halacha is or is not  the same.